# Android Studio Wont Launch Ubuntu Could not find main class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am trying to launch android studio but I get this error instantly,

```
Error: Could not find or load main class #
```

It was working before I tried to change the VM settings via
Help> Edit Custom VM Options
to this

```
-Xms1024m 
-Xmx4096m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM 
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=440m 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Go through to this [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/631039/439175)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio **will not launch if there is a # in the vmoptions**

The file that caused this was found in

```
~/.AndroidStudio2.3/studio64.vmoptions
```

Contents:

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx8192m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=440m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Line that causes error:

```
-Xmx8192m # <------ increase this to most of your RAM
```

To this:

```
-Xmx8192m
```